# Attribute (pool-name="pool_name_here") value is not found in list of jdbc connections

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish

### Problem:

**Error when running java ee projet:**

> Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [K2Fitness-war] :
>   javax.resource.ResourceException: javax.resource.ResourceException:
>   Attribute value (pool-name = java:app/k2fitness) is not found in list
>   of jdbc connection pools.

**glassfish-ressources.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_k2fitness_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="k2fitness"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="root"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/k2fitness?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:apps/jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/k2fitness" object-type="user" pool-name="k2fitness"/>
</resources>
```

On the glassfish admin panel I have the following:

```
JDBC RESOURCES
  -> jdbc/k2fitness (JNDI-NAME | Connected to k2fitness pool )

JDBC CONNECTION POOLS
  -> k2fitness (POOL NAME | Ping successful )
```

k2fitness url: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/k2fitness`

### Question:

Why is it unable to find the pool name "k2fitness" in the list of connection pools when it clearly exists. Any clarity on this would be helpful.

### Additional Information:

I've attempted to change the jndi-name (unsure if it's related to the pool-name issue) without success:

- java:app/jdbc/k2fitness
- jdbc/k2fitness

Comment: The name of the pool is `mysql_k2fitness_rootPool`, see the `name` attribute of the `jdbc-connection-pool` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the pool is `mysql_k2fitness_rootPool`, see the name attribute of the `jdbc-connection-pool` element.

Comment: the hint was close enough to figure the problem the was wrong

Comment: Sorry but what was the fix actually? I am facing a similar problem. Did you have to change something in the glassfish-ressources.xml file in order to successfully deploy the WAR file?

Comment: @JiříKovalský don't remember was 4 years go :S

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to rename the pool java:app/k2fitness? The error says it can not find it.

Comment: Yup, however ":" is not allowed in the name of the pool. And I don't think java:app has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish doesn't accept ":" in the Pool name.
Check the file glass fish-resources.xml 
In 
     
should match with
    
This issue in not explicit ;)